# Gsap min and max for X and Y

Tags: javascript, gsap

Is any option to add min and max value for X and Y position.
Method .to()

I need it for save timeline and angle, but object stop move when reached limit value.

Thank you for your help.

I tried to use snap, but I think its not for this case.
I tried calculate time and position when I need to stop it, but nothing succeeded.

I think better option to set min and max value.

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/GreenSock/embed/NWzzgKO?editors=0010?height=450&slug-hash=NWzzgKO%3Feditors%3D0010&user=GreenSock&tab-bar-color=%23222&name=cp_embed_2#result-box

```
gsap.set(".box", {x: 300, y: 300});

gsap.to(".box", {
  x: 0, 
  y: 0,
  duration: 3,
  modifiers: {
    x: gsap.utils.unitize(gsap.utils.clamp(100, 300))
  }
})
```

In codepen example which helped to me.
Thanks to gsap developer for help.